# sync flask webpage with python code

Tags: python

to turn on my alarm system running on my pi i use 2 scripts, index.html which provides a webpage with an on/off button and webserver.py which communicates the html file and control the main alarm script in a subprocess.
I'm not that good of a coder and the flask code in the .html and .py i used i found after a bit of research, i adapted it for my project and it works ok. I want to change 2 things however.

1. The first (and most important) thing is that the on/off button
   doesn't save the status of the alarm; i i turn it on on my phone and
   when my wife's phone logs in after that the state of the button come
   always to the default which is off. We can turn the alarm off in
   that case by pressing on and then off but i would prefer the button
   would sync with all the connected devices but i have no idea how to
   do that.
2. -2th (not so important), i would like to change the slider to a button with a different on/off image to make a better integration in
       the html layout (still to do).

Hope anyone can help. Here are the codes:

```
    <!doctype html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
h3, h4 {text-align: center;}
span {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(
    // When the LED button is pressed (change)
    // do an ajax request to server to change LED state
    function()
    {
        $('#flip-1').change(function()
        {
        $.getJSON('/_led', {state: $('#flip-1').val()});
        });
    }
    );
</script>
<!-- Simple JQuery Mobile page that display the button state on the breadoard -->
<!-- You can also change the LED state with the slider switch -->
<!-- The Raspberry Pi uptime is displayed in the footer (Jinja2 expands the template tag) -->
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div><h3>Alarm System Web Control V1.0</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <form>
    <p>Alarm is <span id="buttonState"></span></p>
    <br>
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" style="float: left;">
        <option value="off" selected="selected">UIT</option>
        <option value="on">AAN</option>
    </select>
    </form>
  </div>
 <div data-role="footer">
     <div><h4>Time System Is {{uptime}}</h4></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import webguitest
import time
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

P2 = 8 # redled

# return index page when IP address of RPi is typed in the browser
@app.route("/")
def Index():
    return render_template("index.html", uptime=GetUptime())

# ajax GET call this function to set led state
# depeding on the GET parameter sent
@app.route("/_led")
def _led():
    state = request.args.get('state')
    if state=="on":
#       time.sleep(60) #give owner time to clear before alarm starts
        webguitest.LEDon()
    else:
        webguitest.LEDoff()
    return ""

def _reboot():
    state = request.args.get('state')
    if state=="on":
        p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "reboot"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    else:
        webguitest.LEDoff()
    return ""


# ajax GET call this function periodically to read button state
# the state is sent back as json data
@app.route("/_button")
def _button():
    if webguitest.ReadButton():
        state = "pressed"
    else:
        state = "not pressed"
    return jsonify(buttonState=state)

def GetUptime():
# get uptime from the linux terminal command
    from subprocess import check_output
    output = check_output(["uptime"])
    # return only uptime info
    uptime = output[output.find("up"):output.find("user")-5]
    return uptime

# run the webserver on standard port 80, requires sudo
if __name__ == "__main__":
    webguitest.Init()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: For problem number 1 you will either need to save the state of the alarm in a file or database, and then read and write the alarm status from the  database. I would probably go with sqlite http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlite3/. For the second something like bootstrap switch should be easy to implement http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/

Comment: Create a service (python) for save state, log, warnings, errors, UAC(service because you can't give hardvare permission to web user(bad idea)).Don't mix file and hardware permissions(root to web, root to flask, etc.)